# How to to net.connect via a socks5 proxy?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to bridge a websocket to a socks5. Basically I created a websocket server that listen to request and turn into

```
const socket = net.connect(port, host, ()=>{
  socket.write(Buffer.from(buf));
});
```

Now I tried using `proxysocket` and do

```
const socket = proxysocket.create(proxy_host, proxy_port);
socket.connect(port, host,()=>{
  console.log('hi');
  socket.write(Buffer.from(buf));
});
```

Yet it never gets to 'hi'.

Comment: Before you call `socket.connect`, install event listeners for `error` and `close` events on the `socket` and write logs from those listeners if they fire.  That should give you more information about why the `connect` does not succeed.

Comment: Error or close was never fired. It hangs forever unless I set timeout...